# Expired Certificate in Cosmos API

Tags: fiware, filab, fiware-cosmos

Using WebHDFS API of Cosmos generates an expired certificate response.

Using this url: https://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org:13000/

we can see certificate seems expired[image: Expired Certificate]

Do we need updated certificate or any way to go around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate must be renewed, for sure. In the meantime, you can simply ignore the certificate. If you are using `curl`, use the `-k` option:

```
$ curl -k -X POST "https://cosmos.lab.fiware.org:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&username=frb@tid.es&password=MY_PASSWORD_IS_PRIVATE"
```

Comment: I'm using a library in Dart and can't ignore the certificate

Comment: OK, I'll renew the certificate.

Comment: It should have been renewed with a large expiration time.